# MATLAB Array Iteration & Fieldname

Tags: matlab, random, iteration, cell

I'm really struggling to do what I want with this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm looping through an array X number of times, displaying an array of images in a randomised manner. What I want to do is retrieve the name of each image that is being currently displayed in the random order, and the array it belongs to, as each image is displayed in the loop, and store the two in separate variables.

```
images.blue = imread('blue.bmp');
images.red = imread('red.bmp');
images.green = imread('green.bmp');
images.yellow = imread('yellow.bmp');
colours = {images.blue, images.red, images.green, images.yellow}
cata = {images.blue, images.red}
catb = {images.green, images.yellow}
```

So for example if `images.blue` is being displayed on the screen while the loop is iterating through the array, I want the name `blue` to be saved in variable `CurrentFieldname`.

```
for count = 1;
    names = (fieldnames(images));
while count <= 5
    for n = randperm(length(colours));     
   d =(colours{n}); 
   imshow(d);
   pause(1)           
   CurrentFieldName = (names {n});        
    end
    count = count+1;   
end
break
end
```

What happens with the above code is that after all the images have been displayed, every iteration up till the condition is satisfied, the field name of the last displayed image is stored in `CurrentFieldname`.

The above is not what I want. After every time an image is displayed in the iterating loop, I want the field `CurrentFieldname`, to contain the name of the image that is being displayed. Then, during each interation through the loop, I would like to compare the `CurrentFieldName` with `cata` and `catb`, to see which array `CurrentFieldName` belongs to. Then, record this into a separate variable, `CurrCat`. E.g.

```
if CurrentFieldname == cata
    CurrCat = a;
```

I would just like to have both of these variables, `CurrentFieldName` and `CurrCat`, contain the relevant information at the end of every iteration. Then they would both be overwritten by the information corresponding to the next image that is randomly displayed and so forth.

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Experimenting with the Stroop Effect?

Comment: This can be done of course, however, I'm curious, why going through all that hassle when you can number code the few colors you'll have, i.e., 1=red, 2=blue, etc... wouldn't this be much easier?

Comment: @natan, not Stroop, but another experiment. The above is just an example so I can work out what needs to be done and how, understand and learn from it, then adapt it to my real experiment. There will be around 50 images in the full one. The problem is that i'm trying to record which image is shown each time, and which category it belongs to. These two things specifically are what have been causing me the issues, as I can't seem to get my head round the best way to structure it all, to ensure a simple code which will store the details I need into separate variables, after each image iteration.

Comment: @natan, if the 1=red, 2=blue method is the simplest for what I want to do, then I am all for it. I'm just not sure how to do it, as retrieving the fieldname and category with every iteration is giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try:

```
colors = {'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow' }; % existing colors, assuming for each color there is a .bmp image
NC = numel( colors ); % number of colors
% read the images once
for ci=1:NC
    img.(colors{ci}) = imread( [colors{ci}, '.bmp' ] );
end
NumIters = 1; % number of iterations over all colors
% reapeat as many times 
for itr = 1:NumIters
     ord = randperm( NC ); % permutation for this iteration
     for ci = ord(:)', %'
         CurrentFieldName = colors{ci};
         imshow( img.(colors{ci}) ); % display the current color image
         title( colors{ci} );
         tic;
         % your code here processing img.(colors{ci})
         Response = myFun( img.(colors{ci}) );
         ResponseTime = toc; % record timing of processing
         save( sprintf('data_for_itr%03d_color%02d.mat', itr, ci ),...
              'CurrentFieldName', 'Response', 'ResponseTime' );
     end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a try and let you know.